# Convert Maybe to Single from another source if Maybe completes

Tags: java, kotlin, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I would like to build a `Repository` class that returns a `Single<Something>`.

The class should first look in a `Cache` which returns `Maybe<Something>` and if the `Maybe` completes go off to my `Service` that returns `Single<Something>`

```
interface Cache {
    fun getSomething(): Maybe<Something>   
}

interface Service {
    fun getSomething(): Single<Something>   
}

class Repository (
    private val cache: Cache,
    private val service: Service
) {

    fun getSomething(): Single<Something> {
      return cache.getSomething()
               .????(feed.getSomething()) //onCompleteTransformToSingle() or similar
    }
}
```

I have searched through the JavaDoc but it does not seem that a transformer for this scenario exists.

Is there a nice way of handling this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two fairly simple options you could use. The first I find more explicit. The second has the benefit that you will call the network on any error in the cache.

These assume a Maybe is returned from the cache. For example if no value is found in the cache, return Maybe.empty()

1) If there is an empty in the stream, switchIfEmpty() will use the alternate observable which calls the network. If no empty is in the stream, the network will never be called.

```
override fun getSomething(): Single<Something> {
      return cache.getSomething()
        .switchIfEmpty(
          Maybe.defer {
            feed.getSomething().toMaybe()
          }
        )
        .toSingle()
  }
```

2) An empty maybe will return an error when cast toSingle(), triggering the network call.

```
override fun getSomething(): Single<Something> {
      return cache.getSomething()
        .toSingle()
        .onErrorResumeNext {
           feed.getSomething()
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need to perform RxJava operations using metadata (absence of cached result), you may have to transform your observer chain into a metadata stream, using `materialize()`.

(Apologies for my lack of fluency in Kotlin)

```
fun getSomething(): Single<Something> {
  return cache.getSomething()
    .toObservable()
    .materialize()
    .take(1)
    .flatMap( it.hasValue() ? Single.just( it.getValue() )
              : Single.fromCallable( apiCall() )
      );
}
```

The `materialize()` operator turns the observer stream into a stream of `Notification`s. You can then inspect the first notification, and if it has a value, use that. Otherwise, make your network call.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following flatMap call with 3 params for Maybe

```
public final <R> Maybe<R> flatMap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends MaybeSource<? extends R>> onSuccessMapper,
        Function<? super Throwable, ? extends MaybeSource<? extends R>> onErrorMapper,
        Callable<? extends MaybeSource<? extends R>> onCompleteSupplier)
```

Example

```
class Repository (
    private val cache: Cache,
    private val service: Service
) {

    fun getSomething(): Single<Something> {
      return cache.getSomething()
                .flatMap(
                    Function {
                        Single.just(it) // onSuccess
                    },
                    Function {
                        Single.error(it) // onError
                    },
                    Callable {
                        feed.getSomething() // onComplete
                    }
                
    }
```

Or

```
class Repository (
    private val cache: Cache,
    private val service: Service
) {

    fun getSomething(): Single<Something> {
      return cache.getSomething()
                .flatMap(
                    {
                        Single.just<Something>(it) // onSuccess
                    },
                    {
                        Single.error(it) // onError
                    },
                    {
                        feed.getSomething() // onComplete
                    }
                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**defaultIfEmpty** can be used to handle empty Maybe result when converting it to a Single.

Here is an example of how it can be done:

```
    override fun getSomething(): Single<Something> {
      return cache.getSomething()
        .defaultIfEmpty(feed.getSomething())
  }
```